# What does binary scan "xyz" H* do?

Tags: tcl

I see the following code:

```
binary scan  "xyz"  H* var
```

It puzzles me: `binary scan` is supposed to scan a binary stream and construct string type variables, but here it is "xyz" ...?

I did the following experiment inside tclsh:

```
% puts $var
78797a    <== what is this?

% binary scan $var @1H y    <== I mean to get "y"
1

% puts $y     <== but I get "3"?
3
```

I am lost.

Could you explain what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Does it help to know that the hexadecimal value of the character 'x' is 0x78?  Or that `binary scan \x78\x79\x7a H* var2` is identical to your example? The examples in the 'binary scan' manual page under the 'H' conversion code explain it pretty well, I think.

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
binary scan  "xyz"  H* var
```

The binary string is `xyz`, which is three bytes that are the ASCII values for `x`, `y` and `z`. We then ask for the `var` variable to be given a sequence hex digits of the scanned bytes in big endian order (very much the right thing for dealing with strings, BTW!) with twice as many hex digits as there are bytes in the binary string (because `*`). Let's double check with what the [documentation says](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/binary.htm#M47):

> The data is turned into a string of *count* hexadecimal digits in high-to-low order represented as a sequence of characters in the set “0123456789abcdef”. The data bytes are scanned in first to last order with the hex digits being taken in high-to-low order within each byte. Any extra bits in the last byte are ignored. If *count* is `*`, then all of the remaining hex digits in *string* will be scanned. If *count* is omitted, then one hex digit will be scanned. For example,
>
> ```
> binary scan \x07\xC6\x05\x1f\x34 H3H* var1 var2
> ```
>
> will return `2` with `07c` stored in *var1* and `051f34` stored in *var2*.

Now, there are three bytes in `xyz` so there are six digits in `78797a`. The first two hex digits, `78` are the the hex for the ASCII version of `x` ([check for yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set)), and similarly for `79` and `7a`.

When you then do:

```
binary scan $var @1H y
```

you move the internal cursor into the string to the byte for the ASCII for `8` (because zero-based indexing), `\x38`, and because there's no `count` given to the `H`, it gets the *first* hex digit of `38` (i.e., `3`) and puts that in the `y` variable.

To actually retrieve the `y`, you can just use `string index` or `string range` on the original binary string (as all Tcl's string commands work just fine on binary data). Or you use `string range` to get the hex digits out of `var` and `binary format` to convert back:

```
binary format H* [string range $var 2 3]
```

---

It's probably not a good idea to `binary scan` the results of `binary scan`. It's totally legal to do so, but the results are going to be unlikely to illuminate.